# LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00001F) __imp__xmlFree

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, libxml2

Trying to run libxml2 XML create document sample in CLR form application:

```
#pragma once


#include <iconv.h>
#include <libxml\xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml\parser.h>


#if defined(LIBXML_TREE_ENABLED) && defined(LIBXML_OUTPUT_ENABLED)
int
mainas(void)
{

    xmlNodePtr n;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *xmlbuff;
    int buffersize;

    /*
     * Create the document.
     */
    doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
    n = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "root");
    xmlNodeSetContent(n, BAD_CAST "content");
    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, n);

    /*
     * Dump the document to a buffer and print it
     * for demonstration purposes.
     */
    xmlDocDumpFormatMemory(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize, 1);
    printf("%s", (char *) xmlbuff);

    /*
     * Free associated memory.
     */
    xmlFree(xmlbuff);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    return (0);

}
#else
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
            "library not configured with tree and output support\n");
    return (1);
}
#endif



namespace createXML {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(608, 374);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

            }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 }
        };
}
```

Got two linking errors:

```
1>createXML.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00001F) __imp__xmlFree
1>createXML.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlFree
```

Where is problem?

UPD

After adding IN_LIBXML got linking errors:

```
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlversion.h(24): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(103): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(108): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(113): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(119): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(129): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(135): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(140): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(142): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(144): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(146): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(148): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(150): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(152): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(154): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(156): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(158): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(160): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(162): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml\xmlmemory.h(164): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(40): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(42): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(45): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(48): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(50): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(54): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(57): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(60): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(63): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(66): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(70): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(73): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(77): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(80): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(84): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(86): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(89): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(93): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(97): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(102): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(108): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(111): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(113): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(116): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(119): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(122): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(125): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(129): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(131): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlstring.h(133): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(30): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(32): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(34): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(36): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(42): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(46): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(50): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(54): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(57): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/dict.h(63): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(51): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(53): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(54): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(57): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(60): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(74): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(78): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(80): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(84): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(90): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(96): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(113): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(115): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(119): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(121): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(141): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(141): error C4394: 'forbiddenExp' : per-appdomain symbol should not be marked with __declspec(dllexport)
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(142): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(142): error C4394: 'emptyExp' : per-appdomain symbol should not be marked with __declspec(dllexport)
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(147): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(150): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(156): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(159): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(163): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(167): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(171): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(179): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(181): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(183): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(188): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(193): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(198): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(202): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/xmlregexp.h(206): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(597): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(603): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(606): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(609): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(614): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(619): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(622): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(630): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(632): error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\include\libxml/tree.h(632): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Comment: where I can set DIN_LIBXML in my Visual C++?

Comment: Yes, I have added path in "Additional Library Directories" like D:\CLibs\libxml2-2.6.30.win32\lib
 But this not helps

Comment: After setting IN_LIBXML got linking errors - cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe . More details in UPD

Comment: Pure assemblies cannot export functions that are callable from native code. If you want to use native DLL exports, you need to compile using mixed mode, with `/clr`. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh.aspx Something about this is strange, though. `__declspec(dllexport)` should only be used when you compile the library. If you are only *using* the library, this should not be defined. Read the library's documentation for information on how to use it properly.

Comment: Did you compile libxml2 as dynamic or static library?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you compiled *libxml2* as static library. In this case, try to define the `LIBXML_STATIC` macro for your client code. Another option is to compile *libxml2* as dynamic library which shouldn't require additional settings for client code.

Don't ever define the `IN_LIBXML` macro.